# Android ASTRO Cannot Locate Download Directory

Tags: apk

I have placed apk in download directory.  I have also downloaded from web into download directory, but ASTRO does not seem to see this directory.  In Astro I see / etc  lib data (empty) and sd (empty).  On the other hand from windows explorer I don't see these files I see

```
F:Android
F:download/ with apks
F:DCIM empty

F:Android/data with some items like cache but not much.
```

So far searching with Astro I could not locate downloaded files in the download directory which I know are on Android.  Any suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: Also the data on F:Android/data really looks nothing like the data directory I am seeing on ASTRO???

Comment: Now I could place files in location other than download in case this is somehow not visible to ASTRO, but I am not really seeing these other areas like var etc etc from the Windows side.

Comment: All I can see is the directories under F: that I have listed above. The download looks the same as what should be on the device but I am not seeing all the other android linux directories.  What do I need to do see more from ASTRO like download? or see more of Android direcotries from the windows side?  Thanks

Comment: You really need to edit your question (and comments) so that your directory paths make sense.  Also, try to make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: @Androider: Please take the information from your comments and edit it into your question.

Comment: Are you trying to find the file(s) while still in USB mount mode? Your phone can't read the SD card while it is so mounted. Unmount and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/mnt/sdcard/download`.  And based on Al's comment, I suggest making sure your phone is not connected to your PC and then reboot the phone before looking there.